# Get Array from string.xml

Tags: android

I have a string in my `string.xml` whose structure is like this.

string.xml

```
<string name="my" formatted="false">As*#*Bs*#*Cs</string>
```

and I am fetching this string in my main file like this.

main.java

```
String h1 = getResource().getString(R.string.my);
```

and my output is like this.

```
h1=As*#*Bs*#*Cs
```

but I want output in an array without regex like this.

```
h1[0]="As",h1[1]="Bs",h1[2]="Cs";
```

What should I change to get the above output? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: <string name="you">%$&amp;my(0)*#*hello*#*bye</string> what should i do for this mean now i want output in which i should get hello,bye,the element on h1[0] index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
String[] stringArray = h1.split("\\*#\\*");
```

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to store your string as a string array in the following manner :

```xml
<resources>
    <string-array name="my">
        <item>As</item>
        <item>Bs</item>
        <item>Cs</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

You will be able to retrieve you array in the following manner :

```java
String [] h1 = getResources().getStringArray ( R.array.my );
```

Answer (score 0):

After stroring your xml string in h1 String . You need to apply **split** on h1 string.

Try this.

```
String h1= "As*#*Bs*#*Cs";
String[] test = h1.split("\\*#\\*"); 

for(String str : test)
{
      Log.i("==============", str);
}
```

**Output :**

```
I/==============( 1321): As
I/==============( 1321): Bs
I/==============( 1321): Cs
```

You can use `str[0] , str[1] and str[2]` to get respective string.

Comment: <string name="you">%$&amp;my(0)*#*hello*#*bye</string>
i want output like this from this string like this
output[0]=h1[0]="As", output[1]="hello",output[2]="bye"